# How to place the label center along the width?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to place the label at the center along the width of the window. I cannot achieve it using 'anchor' well. I am new to Python.

My code is:

```
window = Tk()
window.geometry("440x640") 
window.title("Title")
Label(window, text="this text to center",font=("Calibri",32)).grid(row=0)
Label(window, text="Second").grid(row=1)
e2 = Entry(window)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: which label do you want centered? do you want it to be independent of the other windows (eg: if the user resizes the window, is it ok that the other widgets might go under the label). Are you asking how to center it using `grid`, or do you care whether it uses something else?  If the user resizes the window do you want it to remain centered? Most layout questions depend on exactly what all the other widgets are doing; there could be a dozen different ways to center a widget. The right one depends on many factors unique to your specific layout.

Comment: I want the first label to be centered. Yes, I want it to be done using the grid. For now that all I want.

Answer (score 0):

By default, items are centered in a grid cell without you having to do anything. The problem you have is that the column that contains the cell is only wide enough for the largest item in that column, which in this case is the title. Thus, it's centered in its cell, but the cell is exactly as wide as the label so it doesn't look centered.

If you want the title to span the width of the *window* (rather than the cell), you need to use the `columnspan` option so that it goes across all of the columns that you are using.

For example:

```
l1 = Label(window, ...)
l1.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
```

However, it still will not appear centered, because columns 0 and 1 will only be as large as their largest items, which leaves some extra space in the GUI since you explicitly set the width of the window. You need to do one of two things: make the window smaller (or let Tkinter determine the best size for you, which is usually the right solution), or designate that either column 0 or 1 (or both) will expand to fill any extra space.

For the first case, simply remove the call to `geometry`. For the second, use `columnconfigure` on the root to have one or both columns have a "weight", which means they will expand to take up extra space.

```
window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

As a general rule of thumb when using `grid`, you should always give at least one row and at least one column a weight, so that the widgets will expand to fit the available space.